# Bootstrap modal in iframe

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, conflict

I have a page with `iframe` on it and where `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.js` are loaded before the body tag.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<iframe src="test.html"></iframe>
<script src="/assets/8bf00db7/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/383389f4/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In **test.html** scripts are loaded in the same way.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<button>Click</button>
<div class="modal">Model content here</div>
<script src="/assets/8bf00db7/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/383389f4/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

There is also **main.js** file with this code.

```
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        $('.modal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

When I click, I get an error: **Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function**. Please help to fix it.

Comment: in your test.html, move all scripts in `<head>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imports must be done in the header tag:

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="/assets/8bf00db7/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/383389f4/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<button>Click</button>
<div class="modal">Model content here</div>

</body>
</html>
```

simple working example of bootstrap modal: http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/